# How to know the number of collections exists in already initiated JSON Store in IBM Worklight application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using worklight7.1 (Mobilefirst) and I have a small query related to JSON Store.

I have initiated a JSON Store

```
var collections = {
    collection1: {
        searchFields: {
            a:'string',
            b:'string'
        },
    collection2: {
        searchFields: {
            a:'string',
            b:'string'
        }
    }
};

WL.JSONStore.init(collections);
```

Now as the collections are already initiated, so I want to know the number of collections exists in JSON Store.

If any one knows the best ways of finding number of collections exists in a already initiated JSON Store, please share them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated API for this, so I would say simply store your collections in a way that it will be easier to find it out.

Since you manually define these you should already know the number... but if you require this programmatically, store the collections in an array and whenever you need to know the number, use JS to check how many items (collections) exist in the array.